# Changing loop index

Tags: php, foreach

I have inner loop for the same array, 
but in the inner loop I delete some elements, new array is assigned to the main array, but the problem occurs that the main loop index still unchanged!

```
foreach ($newsletters as $index=>$mainNewsletterObj) {
    // var_dump($newsletters); // it prints new DATA !

         // the problem is here !
    echo 'up index is '.$index .'<br/>';  // it prints old index!!!!!!!!!!

      // make a copy of main array
      $newslettersArray = $newsletters; 

        //inner loop
     foreach ($newslettersArray as $key => $newsletterObj) {

    if ($newsletterObj['month'] == 3 );

         unset($newslettersArray[$key]);  //remove element
      } else
      {
     // make a new array of modified one to start index from 0
     $newslettersArray1 = array_values($newslettersArray); // to start index from 0

      // assign new modified array to the original one
     $newsletters = $newslettersArray1;

  }

}   // end inner loop

$index=0;
  echo 'down index is '.$index .'<br/>';  // it prints 0
 }  // end of outer loop
```

Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: Can't you just provide a simplified version of your issue ?

Comment: I did, is it good now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `while (list($index, $mainNewsletterObj) = each($newsletters))` instead of `foreach ($newsletters as $index=>$mainNewsletterObj)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the original array! Create a copy of that array before entering the loop and then remove the elements from the copy, where neccesary.

Comment: I make a copy of the array before entering the inner loop " $newslettersArray = $newsletters;" and I assign the new array to the old one before returning to the outer loop

Comment: You can not (or should not) change Arrays or any kind of collection you are iterating over, while doing so. Always change the copies, not the ones you are iterating over

Comment: use `while (list($index, $mainNewsletterObj) = each($newsletters))` 
instead of `foreach ($newsletters as $index=>$mainNewsletterObj)`

Comment: @Amir, it works well. Please write it in the answers section.